# CTRL-A with visual mode not working

Tags: visual-mode, text-generation

According to the Vim help, using `g CTRL-A` with visual mode should change several lines in A to that in B:

A:

```
1.    
1.    
1.    
1.
```

B:

```
1.    
2.    
3.    
4.
```

In my Vim, the `CTRL-A` is working in normal mode, which increments a number. But when I am using visual mode, whether it is linewise, block or visual, it will not work. For example, when I press `CTRL-A` in a help file, it will have this error:

```
E21: Cannot make changes, 'modifiable' is off
```

But if I use visual mode, there is no such error and no change happens. The same goes for `g CTRL-A` and for an editable file.

How can I solve this problem? There are no requisites listed on the manual of this feature, so I probably won't need to recompile the Vim again?

***EDIT:***

1. `E21` is not the real problem, I just want to use it as an indicator that it doesn't work, i.e. it doesn't change or try to change anything.
2. `:ver` first line output:

   ```
    VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Apr 13 2016 12:09:32)
   ```

   Included patches: 1-1725

Comment: IIRC using `<C-a>` in visual mode was added fairly recently. Which Vim version are you using?

Comment: Just for the record where is the doc saying that `g CTRL-A` increments numbers in visual mode? My Vim 7.4 [`:h g_CTRL-A`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#g_CTRL-A) says that it is used to print memory usage statistics for debugging Vim.

Comment: @statox see [`:h v_g_CTRL-A`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#v_g_CTRL-A). I think Carpetsmoker's right and this has to do with the Vim version. On Arch, or with the pi-rho PPA on Ubuntu 14.04, this works, but on Ubuntu 14.04 with the repository Vim (7.4, patches 1-52), it doesn't work.

Comment: @muru Thanks for the link I didn't find the topic because it is not included in my version so I think you and Carpetsmoker are right it must be because OP doesn't have the correct version.

Comment: How can we download such a version of Vim? I have updated mine and it still is not correct. Cloning the git file on github is also not working.

Answer (score -2):

Seems like `c-a` has been mapped to some plugin in your vim. (In that plugin, `c-a` is mapped to some 'modifiable' action, so that you get that error message....)
You might try `:vmap` to list all key mappings in visual mode and check if there is some plugin or custom key binding who is using `c-a`.

Comment: This doesn't account for `g<C-a>` not working...

Comment: ah....i read the post again, and found out it could be related to 'help files', if you try to 'modify' in that read-only split window, `E21` is the error message. Just tried that and got `E21`, this could be the reason, but it has nothing to do with a normal editable file, just provide more clues here.

Comment: Actually not only help buffer are affected by the `modifiable` setting: The user can use `set nomodifiable` to other buffers if he wishes. See [`:h 'modifiable'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27modifiable%27)

Comment: Actually, `E21` is not the problem, I just want to use it as an indicator that it doesn't work, i.e. it doesn't change or try to change anything.